# Return order of MySQL SHOW COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I need to find the columns in a specific table, which is no problem:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename LIKE '%ColumnPrefix%';
```

But I need to know what order they will be returned, preferably by choosing to order the results ascending alphabetically. I have had no luck with using `ORDER BY`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need such unusual thing from such a black box as a table structure?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? What client are you using, e.g. PHP? Why not just sort the columns on the client?

Comment: MySQL 4.0.16 which is a bit of a pain, shall have a play about  with ordering it with PHP. Brain isn't in gear today it seems(!)

Comment: Any reason you can't load the results into your program and sort them there?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can query the table [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) to get the information that `SHOW COLUMNS` gives you, plus it allows you to use ORDER BY or any other SQL syntax you might want to use:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
  AND column_name LIKE 'ColumnPrefix%'
ORDER BY column_name
```

Comment: +1 Good point - the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database (since 5.0) is probably the most overlooked useful thing in MySQL.

Comment: Am running version 4.0.16 otherwise that would be a great way of doing the job.

Answer (score 6):

Since I have had the exact same problem I will complete Mark's answer.
Here is the exact long version of the 'show columns from table' query:

```
SELECT 
    `column_name` AS `Field`, 
    `column_type` AS `Type`, 
    `is_nullable` AS `Null`, 
    `column_key` AS `Key`, 
    `column_default` AS `Default`, 
    `extra` AS `Extra` 
FROM 
    `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE 
    `table_name`='mytable';
```

With this query you can order the result however you wish by adding ORDER BY.