# How do I use `SHOW COLUMNS` as a valid data source

Tags: mysql, sql, reflection, select

I need to run the following query (this is a simplification of my process):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SHOW COLUMNS FROM T1)
```

It errors out.

Comment: I don't think you can use `SHOW COLUMNS` in a subquery like this.

Comment: @Rahul - I know I can't, looking for a way to emulate this on the mysql level

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
select * from (
    select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where table_name = 'T1'
) dt
```

You cannot use `SHOW COLUMNS` in a subquery, but by using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table, you have much more information available, not only the column name, for instance.

Comment: This takes at least 100x the amount of time as SHOW COLUMNS, though. =\

Answer (score 2):

See this post in SO [Return order of MySQL SHOW COLUMNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544751/return-order-of-mysql-show-columns)

So probably you can use like as per the post

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'tablename' 
 ORDER BY column_name) colinfo
```