# exclude certain items from fields in mysql

Tags: php, dynamic, selection, field

lets say you want to get all the columns of a table, but exclude ones that have for example _images in the name without having to do

```
mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table. " WHERE Field NOT IN ('project_images_1' .etc)")
```

is this possible?

field example:

```
header
bodytext
project_images_1 (exclude)
project_images_2 (exclude)
```

Comment: You know that MySQL supports subqueries? Also consider to use `mysqli_*` functions for new code.

Comment: example? for this type of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I could do it with the `LIKE` operator:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE NOT Field LIKE '%_images%';
```

Or if you need more control, this might be helpful:

```
$query = <<<SQL
SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE Field NOT IN (
    SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = $table
    AND column_name LIKE 'project_images_%'
);
SQL;
```

This works by using the [information schema tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html) (maybe that's what you look for anyway) within [a so called subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html).

Related:

- [How do I use `SHOW COLUMNS` as a valid data source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6345870/367456)

Comment: in the second example you gave why is it necessary to select the column name again 'SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'

Comment: That needs to return a resultset with one column per row, otherwise `IN` would not work. And that column needs to be the column name naturally, otherwise the `IN` would not make any sense.